# How to flip string using linux in specific columns

Tags: linux, bash

I have few columns as shown below:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 a/t t/g g/t f/g
col3 col2 col4 col5 t/a g/t f/g g/t
```

I would need to flip the values in columns after 4, and the sample output is shown below:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 t/a g/t t/g g/f
col3 col2 col4 col5 a/t t/g g/f t/g
```

I tried using the -rev option in bash but it prints the whole row in the inverted direction (mirror image). Is there an alternate solution for this just to flip the strings as shown in the output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-rev` option of what?

Comment: rev for the whole file: cat file | rev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what the first 4 column may contain, so I assume this would be enough

```
sed 's/\(\w\)\/\(\w\)/\2\/\1/g' <yourfile>
```

like:

```
$ cat test
col1 col2 col3 col4 t/a g/t t/g g/f
col3 col2 col4 col5 a/t t/g g/f t/g

$ sed 's/\(\w\)\/\(\w\)/\2\/\1/g' test
col1 col2 col3 col4 a/t t/g g/t f/g
col3 col2 col4 col5 t/a g/t f/g g/t
```

if you want to save the result to a file, redirect sed output:

```
$ sed 's/\(\w\)\/\(\w\)/\2\/\1/g' test > newfile
```

Comment: the first four columns doesn't have data in the format which is present after column4. However, i tried your solution and it doesn't work as it gives the output as it is in the original file.

Comment: @user1779730 it works, but actually had a typo that would reverse only fifth column, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane 'print join " ", @F[0..3], map { scalar reverse $_}  @F[4..$#F]'
```